# IllegalArgumentException: Entity must be managed to call remove

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, ejb, illegalargumentexception

Controller page has following code

```
                BigDecimal id=new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("empId"));
                employee.setEmpno(id);
                flag = factory.removeEmployee(employee);
```

`TransactionFactory` class

```
    public final class EntityTransactionFactory implements TransactionFactory{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManagerFactory Factory;
    private EntityManager Manager;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction Transaction;
    private static final TransactionFactory transaction = new EntityTransactionFactory();

    private EntityTransactionFactory() {

    }

    public static TransactionFactory getInstance() {
        return transaction;
    }


    /**
     * @return the Factory
     */
    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory getFactory() {
        Factory= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SampleBeanPU");
        return Factory;
    }

    /**
     * @return the Manager
     */
    @Override
    public EntityManager getManager() {
        Manager=getFactory().createEntityManager();
        return Manager;
    }

    /**
     * @return the Transaction
     */
    @Override
    public UserTransaction getTransaction() {
        try {
            Transaction = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            Transaction=null;
        }
        return Transaction;
    }
}
```

`emp` variable name of `Emp` type.

```
        TransactionFactory factory=EntityTransactionFactory.getInstance();
        factory.getTransaction().begin();
        factory.getManager().joinTransaction();

        Emp ref= factory.getManager().getReference(Emp.class, emp.getEmpno());
        System.out.println(ref.getEname());
        factory.getManager().remove(factory.getManager().merge(ref));
        System.out.println(factory.getTransaction().getStatus());
        factory.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println(factory.getTransaction().getStatus());
        //factory.getManager().flush();
        factory.getManager().close();
        factory.getFactory().close();
```

But, getting following exception, which is pointing on above code.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must be managed to call remove: com.entity.Emp[ empno=1234 ], try merging the detached and try the remove again.
```

Comment: Your manager.merge() method probably doesn't return the correct instance of Emp.

Comment: So. how to resolve this ?

Comment: I have verified the reference by putting `System.out.println(ref.getEname());` and it is returning correct employee name

Comment: If every method of the unknown manager class opens a session and closes it, the entity becomes unmanaged as soon as the method returns. Why the hell don't you show your code?

Comment: @JBNizet Code added. and `getManager()` will return `EntityManager` instance;

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You're creating a brand new instance of EntityManagerFactory at each call. And creating a new EntityManager at each call. An EntityManagerFactory must be created once and only once. It contains all the metadata about all your entities and their associations. And An EntityManager must be created, used inside a transaction by several methods, then closed. Not recreated for every single method call.

Comment: You're inside an EJB container. Use it as it should be. Let the EJB container handle the EMF, the EntityManager, the transactions and simply inject the EntityManager into your declaratively transactional methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @JBNizet

I'm creating instance of `EntityManagerFactory` only once by putting into private constructor and retrieving instance by getter method of this class.

And for removing entity I used following code

```
        Emp ref = factory.getManager().find(Emp.class, emp.getEmpno());           
        factory.getManager().remove(ref);
```

And, It works.!!